# Convert HTML into WIki Format

Tags: c#, html, wiki

Is there any way to convert HTML code into wiki format? I just need some formatting tags (bold, italic, hyperlink, etc.). If I try to use Pandoc, it needs to be installed, but I don’t want that. Are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 1):

I have done this with [DotNetWikiBot](http://dotnetwikibot.sourceforge.net/) however it hasn't worked very well in my case.  Probably because I used an HTML document which was produced by a MS Word export.

```
    var un = "me";
    var pw = "123xyz";
    Site site = new Site("http://wiki.company.int", un, pw);

    Page p = new Page(site);
    p.LoadFromFile("C:\\DotNetWikiBot_3.15\\wordExport.htm");
    p.ConvertHtmlMarkupToWikiMarkup();
    p.title = "New Page"; // http://wiki.company.int/New_Page
    // p.Save(); would upload a new page to the website
    p.SaveToFile("C:\\DotNetWikiBot_3.15\\out.md");
```

It works better when you export from word to a filtered html (whatever that means).  It produces some strange characters like �. It's probably still better than nothing because it adds tables and headings.

Any tips from the DotNetWikiBot team would be appriated

Answer (score 0):

There are online converters available. I never tried any of them, because I never made a wiki page.

You could try this one: http://w-i-k-i.appspot.com/.

Good Luck.